# Mongoose Populate not populating the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

The following are two blocks of code, the first one is my Schema and the second one is my query. The Payment model is getting saved and it has the id referring to the user. Can I know where I am going wrong, is there any thing wrong with the fundamental ?

Here is my schema of User and Payment
User:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var paymentSchema = new Schema({
    amount: Number,
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    payment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Payment'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Payment', paymentSchema);
```

Here is my query which I am using to populate using promise:

```
User.findOne({email: req.query.email})
    .populate('payment')
    .select('_id payment')
    .then(function(user) {
        res.json(user);
    });
```

Comment: Is it goes to circular dependency , why to refer payment (_id) on user table? What shows the error goes down?

Comment: Even neglecting the select portion, doesn't solve the problem. There is no error showing up, it just shows: `payment: []` Moreover I don't understand your english

Comment: Try [exec()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) instead of `then()`.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the _id of payment to the payment array field.